# Change Of Visa Status From J1 to F1: No Reply From USCIS and About To Miss Semester Start Dates

Tags: usa, student-visa

Here is my situation: I have applied for a change of status from a J1 visa to F1. My university start dates is this Tuesday and I still have not heard back from USCIS. I have spoken to both my home university and university in the U.S. and they are both happy to transfer me to fall semester.

My questions is what do I do? If my COS is eventually approved do I still have to go back to Australia now that my semester start date is well over 5 months away and start a new visa application or do I just give USCIS my new I-20? Should I even bother waiting for a reply now that it is too late or if I leave the US and abandon my application will this reflect badly when I go home to apply for F1 again? Is it likely my application will now be denied anyway because I have missed the semester start date?

Please if anyone can help with even a little bit of information it would be great! I am so worried and confused about what to do not to mention upset I will miss start date. I have called to find information but the officers aren't very helpful.